# Where do pions get angular momentum from?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, standard-model, pions

If a neutral meson carrying intrinsic spin equal to 1 decays into a pair of charged pions, how can they possibly conserve angular momentum? Pions have no spin and if they originate from the same point then their relative motion can't generate angular momentum either.

Won't they just go their separate ways? How can there be orbital angular momentum between them?

Comment: They'll go their separate ways, in a p-wave: non-uniformly, mindful of the spherical harmonic $Y_1^m$ angular distribution imposed by the spin of the parent particle.  What is the question?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Isn't p related to orbital angular momentum?

Comment: Yes: the unit spin of the parent particle converts to orbital angular momentum in the daughters. Total spin + orbital is conserved, as it should; you recall the separate components interconvert, no?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let’s see a concrete example:

[image: rhopi=1]

$ρ_0 \rightarrow π^+π^-$

This is an indicative  first-order Feynman diagram for this decay  .

> Pions have no spin and if they originate from the same point then their relative motion can't generate angular momentum either.

It is a quantum mechanical reaction. As you see, the two pions do not originate from the same point. In general, in Feynman diagrams, the vertices are only out of three lines and one of them is the outgoing one.

This leaves leeway for orbital angular momentum to exist between them, when the final two pions are described in terms of a wave function, which will carry the spin 1 of the rho by conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: Note that $\rho^0\to\pi^+\pi^-$ is allowed, but $\rho^0\to\pi^0\pi^0$ is forbidden, probably because exchange symmetry forbids two identical $\pi^0$ to occupy a negative-parity $L=1$ final state.

Comment: presumably this just **a** first-order feynman diagram for the decay? I assume the gluon could also interact with the anti-up quark instead of the up quark

Comment: @user253751 sure, all the quantum number conserving replacements can be drawn, it is indicative to show the quantum complexity.

Comment: @annav Can this be regarded as evidence that virtual particles actually exist, rather than merely being mathematical artefacts?

Comment: @Struggling_Student  I do not think so. Incoming and outgoing particles exist, but the quantum number conservation is just algebra, it does not require to name as particle the carrier of thedp/dt with the quantum numbers.

Comment: @annav What I meant was that two particles can't have classical momentum if they originate from one point. These pions don't originate in one point so there must be a third particle (the virtual boson) that separates their points of origins. So that boson does actually exist for a while and travels a short distance.

Comment: @Struggling_Student what exists is an **off mass shell fourvector** with the quamtum numbers that describe the boson and a variable mass http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html